# grouping excel rows with EPPLUS

Tags: c#, excel, vba, epplus

what i need is group rows when the value of the row is the same as the previous row, the value of "B3" is the same of "B2", like this:

[image]

i´m usin c# with epplus, and i see how can i do something similar to this with the outline option, and is similar to what i want, but this option have some disadvantages, such as that which doesn´t automatically group based on values and can´t do various groups....

is it  possible to do this with EPPLUS?  if it´s not posible, how can i add the vba code to c#?, i try this:

```
  StringBuilder vbaCode = new StringBuilder();

  vbaCode.AppendLine("Sheets('Sheet1').Activate");
  vbaCode.AppendLine("Range('A1: D11').Select");
  vbaCode.AppendLine("Selection.Subtotal GroupBy:= 1, Function:= xlSum, TotalList:= Array(2, 3),Replace:= True, PageBreaks:= False, SummaryBelowData:= True");
pck.Save();
```

but not work, i can´t open the Excel file.

EDIT

With sugested now i try Interop with the group function, but for a extrain reason he is grouping columns not rows, this is the code:

```
 var ExApp = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
 Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbooks Wbs = ExApp.Workbooks;
 Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook Wb = Wbs.Open(fi.FullName.ToString());
 Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Sheets wss = Wb.Worksheets;
 Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet Ws = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet)wss.get_Item("Sheet1");
 Ws.Range["A6:A10"].Group();
 Ws.Outline.SummaryRow =Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlSummaryRow.xlSummaryAbove;
 ExApp.Visible = true;
```

Comment: EPPlus can't do something that isn't possible with Excel. If you can do something with Excel or VBA though, you can do it with EPPlus. You don't need VBA to group rows, you can just write the same logic in C# - eg `sheet.Cells["A1:D11"]` will return an ExcelRange on which you can call `Group`

Comment: yes, is supossed that all that yo can do with Excel yo ca do with EEPLUS, but i can,t see how to do this,  in Excel this option is in the Data tab, subtotal option. If yo know how to do it this with EPPLUS please put a simple example of how this work. when i put **sheet.Cells["A1:D11"] ** dont see the group option, i can see that exist one named group by, but not understand how it Works.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I see this is already answered but figured I would provide an EPPlus way which you can certainly do but you do need to manually create the sum cells:

```
[TestMethod]
public void Row_Grouping_Test()
{
    //http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41636336/grouping-excel-rows-with-epplus

    //Throw in some data
    var datatable = new DataTable("tblData");
    datatable.Columns.AddRange(new[]
    {
        new DataColumn("Header", typeof (string)), new DataColumn("Col1", typeof (int)), new DataColumn("Col2", typeof (int)), new DataColumn("Col3", typeof (object))
    });

    for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        var row = datatable.NewRow();
        row[0] = $"Header {i}"; row[1] = i; row[2] = i * 10; row[3] = Path.GetRandomFileName(); datatable.Rows.Add(row);
    }

    //Create a test file
    var fi = new FileInfo(@"c:\temp\Row_Grouping_Test.xlsx");
    if (fi.Exists)
        fi.Delete();

    using (var pck = new ExcelPackage(fi))
    {
        var worksheet = pck.Workbook.Worksheets.Add("Sheet1");
        worksheet.Cells.LoadFromDataTable(datatable, false);

        worksheet.Cells["A11"].Value = "TOTAL";
        worksheet.Cells["B11"].Formula = "SUBTOTAL(9,B2:B10)";
        worksheet.Cells["C11"].Formula = "SUBTOTAL(9,C2:C10)";
        worksheet.Row(11).Style.Font.Bold = true;

        //Row Group 1 (start with 1 since row index is 1-based)
        for (var i = 1; i <= datatable.Rows.Count; i++)
            worksheet.Row(i).OutlineLevel = 1;

        pck.Save();
    }
}
```

Which looks like this:

[image]

Comment: Perfect, is just what i need

Comment: Something readers may want to note is that if you want this to behave like the 'Subtotal' shortcut that Excel gives on the 'Data' tab in the ribbon then you can replace the SUM(_range_) functions with SUBTOTAL(9,_range_). The difference being if you add headers to your columns and add filters to those headers then SUBTOTAL will update based on the filtered data, SUM will not. Easily overlooked when automating reports that use this functionality.

Comment: @RyanfaeScotland Thats a very good point.  I thnk Subtotal is what the op wanted.  I updated the answer.

Comment: I did consider just adding it as an edit but didn't think it clear enough if OP was aiming to replicate the Subtotal shortcut or the Group shortcut (the Group one acts like your original answer). I'd be inclined to think Subtotal is more useful though so likely a safe bet to apply the update.

Answer (score 0):

I am not familiar with EPPLUS libary. 
but you can achieve that task very easily using `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel` namespace.
and than you can do it like you do it using Vba- (using the `Merge()` method)
note that you will need to add a reference of that namespace to your project. 
here is an example:

```
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication32
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application ExApp;


        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            ExApp = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
            // CREATE A NEW WORKBOOK (you can also open existing workbook using the Open() method)
            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook Wb = ExApp.Workbooks.Add();
            // SET WORKSHEET
            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet Ws = Wb.Worksheets.Add();
            // MERGE CELLS (the answer to your question)
            Ws.Range["A1:G5"].Merge();
            // GROUP ROWS (the final answer to your question)
            Ws.Rows["4:7"].Group();
            ExApp.Visible = true;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, i edited the question, what i want is to group, not merge(the previous image is not clear, sorry), as you sugested i use interop with group() option, but Excel merge columns, not rows, please can you help me?

Comment: Interop requires Excel to be installed on the server. EPPlus generates xlsx files directly.

Comment: @lon see my edit on the answer that is how you group rows...            // 
`Ws.Rows["4:7"].Group();`

Comment: @jonathana THANKS

Comment: @Panagiotis Kanavos how to you know he is running his application on a server? it looks more like a desktop application to me, also the question was not Interop VS EPPLUS

Comment: @honathana EPPlus or the Open XML SDK is used to generate xlsx files without requiring an Office installation. On a server, using Interop would be disastrous. On a desktop, it's just not needed and a cumbersome dependency

Comment: Yes, is an desktop aplication now, and with interop now can work, i need to do something more complex and i´m using epplus because for me is more easy and because yes, in the future it wild like to run in a server, but if i can´t do it with epplus and yes with interop i will execute in another machine not server, It's not my biggest problem.